# Divide $9536$ with a number in order to have an integer as result

Tags: education, divisor-sum

> I need to find a number that divides $9536$ that gives an integer solution

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try 1?

Comment: all the divisors of 9536

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 2):

$14$ divisors:

$1$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $16$, $32$, $64$, $149$, $298$, $596$, $1192$, $2384$, $4768$, $9536$

Answer (score 0):

Write it as the multiplication of prime numbers:

$9536=2^6 \times 149 =2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 149$, plus the fact that all natural numbers are divisible by $1$ and itself, we know that $9536$ is divisible by $1;2;2^2;2^3;2^4;2^5;2^6;149;2 \times 149;2^ 2\times 149;2^3 \times 149;2^4 \times 149;2^5 \times 149;2^6 \times 149;9536$ because the numbers above are contained in the multiplication.